# Laravel.io, Postgresql : syntax error at or near “,”

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I'm trying to setup a Laravel.io community portal as shared on  [Github] (https://github.com/laravelio/portal).

However, I run into the following error when I run `composer setup` in terminal

Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: UPDATE taggables, threads SET taggables.created_at = threads...
                        ^ (SQL: UPDATE taggables, threads SET taggables.created_at = threads.created_at, taggables.updated_at = threads.updated_at WHERE taggables.thread_id = threads.id)

I've checked the SQL statement severally and it checks out okay but no idea why it won't pass at runtime.

This is the Php code from which the SQL is run.

```
 // Refactor tags
    Schema::rename('tagged_items', 'taggables');

    // Fix timestamps on taggables
    if (! app()->runningUnitTests()) {
        DB::statement('UPDATE taggables, threads SET taggables.created_at = threads.created_at, taggables.updated_at = threads.updated_at WHERE taggables.thread_id = threads.id');
    }
```

Comment: You cannot normally update more than one table at a time. With PostGres, there is a way with Common Table Expressions (CTE's), but you are doing it incorrectly: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

Answer (score 1):

SO i posted another question asking for help to restructure the query to a CTE (Common Table Expression) and this was the answer that worked.

```
update taggables ta
set created_at = th.created_at, updated_at = th.updated_at
from threads th
where ta.thread_id = th.id
```

Please refer to the question and answers as per the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60416996/how-to-write-an-update-query-for-multiple-tables-in-common-table-expressions-ct/60417432#60417432)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to relate the tables in a FROM clause or you need to correlate your subquery.  One potential way:

```sql
DB::statement('
update threads
set taggables.created_at = threads.created_at, taggables.updated_at = threads.updated_at
from taggables
where taggables.thread_id = threads.id
');


// or perhaps:


DB::statement('
set threads.created_at = ( select taggables.created_at from taggables  where taggables.thread_id = threads.id), threads.updated_at = ( select taggables.updated_at from taggables  where taggables.thread_id = threads.id)
');
```

Comment: Thanks, @samtax01. I tried the query but it hit another snag again. I have been trying to rewrite it in a Common Table Expressions (CTE's) format but end up being frustrated. Will appreciate it greatly if you could help, please.