# How to write an UPDATE Query for multiple tables in Common Table Expressions (CTE's) format?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression

Ho do I rewrite the following UPDATE statement into a Common Table Expressions (CTE's) format?

```
DB::statement('UPDATE taggables, threads SET taggables.created_at = threads.created_at, taggables.updated_at = threads.updated_at WHERE taggables.thread_id = threads.id');
```

Comment: But why? If this is [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) than your attempt to solve this would be appropriate. If this isn't homework, then it feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and some more details would appropriate (For instance a FROM Clause in your existing UPDATE statement [might be the right solution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-update.html)).

Comment: `UPDATE taggables, threads SET...` Is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see the point for using a CTE here. Since it seems like your purpose is to update `taggables` from `threads`, I would suggest simply using [Postgres' update/join syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html), which goes like:

```
update taggables ta
set created_at = th.created_at, updated_at = th.updated_at
from threads th
where ta.thread_id = th.id
```